# PC Starts back up even when power LEDs are off and after a clean shutdown (Windows 11)

Tags: bios, motherboard, power-supply, shutdown, windows-11

To clarify, when I perform a clean shutdown by going to "Start > Power > Shutdown the PC" it shuts down as usual and stays off for a few seconds (2-3). In this short window of time everything is off, fans, power supply, lights, the indicator lights, everything and then for no apparent reason it starts back up. The only way to shut my PC completely off is to turn off the PSU which is less than ideal.

I've tried turning on and off fast boot, both in bios and in the control panel under power options, I've tried turning off hiberbootenabled & on powerdownaftershutdown respectively through registry, I've turned off the LAN adaptor wake setting, I've tested and tried every bios setting I could find that could be remotely related to the problem and still nothing. I've attached my current relevant bios settings and specs any help would be greatly appreciated :)

BIOS:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0LvI.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dplap.jpg)

Specs:
Windows 11 Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621
i7-11700k
32gb 3200hz XMP
MSI Radeon 6600xt
Gigabyte Z590 Gaming X

Comment: Go into BIOS and look at settings for Wake On whatever. It is likely one of these settings causing the startup. If not and if under warranty, get manufacturer support.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and upload the images instead of linking to a third-party image sharing website?

Comment: @Ramhound sure.

Comment: Have you tried *enabling* `ErP` in `Settings`\`Platform Power` as well?

Comment: @Tom Yan Yeah I have, thought I was onto something there but no luck

Comment: Sounds like some kind of ACPI bug but it doesn't seem like any firmware update mentioned anything about it. Also could it be something wrong with the power header (or maybe the button)? Have you tried disconnecting them and power on with e.g a slot screw driver touch and see if the problem remains when shutting down with nothing connected to the header?

Comment: Huh now that you mention it my case is pretty old it could be that the button is faulty... I'll have to give it a try and report back, thanks :)

Comment: @Tom Yan Unfortunately it didn't work, here's a video of the problem, I shorted the pins before starting to record and you can see the pins are still disconnected [Video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/sAWswEHCVT8pdrYQ9)